# Before/After shortcut in Library|Loupe view

Tags: lightroom, keyboard-shortcuts

In Lightroom, the `\` shortcut works for before/after in the Develop module - is it possible to do before/after in Library|Loupe view?
In that view, the same shortcut is assigned to toggle the filter bar, but it would be nice to have that option without switching to Dev module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. Your best bet for before/after views in the library module is probably to create a virtual copy before you start the editing.